# What to think about, if I want to adopt a second cat from a shelter?

Tags: cats, adoption

I was thinking of new cat's adoption, but a bit afraid that my cat won't accept a new one. I don't want my cat to be jealous of a potential newcomer and take out aggression on him/her. How to understand that she will get along with her relatives?

What points do I need to think about, if I plan to adopt a second cat from the shelter?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Avoid opinion based questions :) Instead ask for instruction how to make a good decision.

Comment: I think similar questions have been asked several times already, https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=introduce+new+cat If you feel your question is different, please edit it and try to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Start by explaining your situation to the shelter staff. They will help you select a cat that gets along well with others, is confident (so they don't trigger your cat to bully them), and is easygoing (so they don't pick fights with your cat).

Tell them your cat's age and temperament. The shelter staff are motivated to help you find the right cat for your home, so the more information you can give them, the better. Also ask their advice about how to introduce the cats.

When you bring the new cat home, keep it in a separate room for perhaps 24 hours, so it has time to relax into the surroundings. Feeding the cats on either side of the door that separates them can help them form positive associations with each other. When they are interested and relaxed, give them some supervised time together and see how things go.

Comment: Generally I agree with this answer, but the common recommendation is to keep them separated for more like a week.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such clear answer! I'll try to do like you said, hope I'll adopt a new cat very soon